# How does having " ?${new Date().getTime()} " updates the image in JS

Tags: javascript, datetime, updates, src

I watched a tutorial where they showed that appending `?${new Date().getTime()}`to the value of src attribute in the image tag, updates the current image with the new image.

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459896/auto-update-image/8459978#8459978), where the first answer to the question has followed the same technique.

Could someone please explain to me the rationale behind the working of this particular technique. Thanks!

Comment: You are setting the image source to the same string. That will not refresh the image, the browser thinks it already has that image, and won't issue another request. Try adding a random query parameter `?${new Date().getTime()}` each time you want to refresh - then the browser should see the image as different resources.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459907/9624435 this answer on linked question gives a insight what it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest explanation is that the browser (and often the server) will cache items in memory to decrease page load times. Therefore, if you have a dozen pages that all are referencing `/images/logo.png`, the image is downloaded once and stored so that it can be re-used on each page. Efficient, right?

Anyways, sometimes images change and you don't want that to happen, so what you do is change the name of the file. For example, `/images/logo.png?15`, `/images/logo.png?16`, `/images/logo.png?17`, etc. The browser no longer attempts to use the cached image because the query is actually different.

The code snippet you've included simply includes the current time to the name of the file in order to make it unique.

Answer (score 0):

Different query parameters can result in a server serving different images, depending on the backend logic. This is *often* not the case - in many setups, requesting the same path with different query parameters will give you the same image in return, but that's not always the case.

If a browser sees an image URL whose image exists in the cache already, it will not download the image again - instead, it'll take the image from the browser cache. But if you change the `src` to one which is *not* in the cache, it will make another request to the server. If the server has changed the image at that endpoint between initial pageload and src change, the new image on the server will be downloaded and displayed on the client.

The `new Date().getTime()` is just a way to append a string which definitely does not exist in the browser cache yet.